# powershell script to append a word to the beginning of a text file

Tags: powershell

I have this code which is appending "segment99" to the beginning of the text file and recreating the whole file with the same name plus suffix "_99". I have two concerns: 1) Takes a long while to run. 2) Modifies the contents of the file - like formatting and special characters like *small boxes* (looks like small boxes when opened in a notepad).

CODE I AM USING NOW:

---

```
Begin
{
$PathData = '<<ESB_Data_Share_HSH>>\RwdPnP'
Get-ChildItem $PathData -Filter '*.txt' | %{
$Start = $true
Get-Content $_.FullName | .{Process{
    if ($Start) {
        '"segment99"' + $_
        $Start = $false
    }
    else {
        $_
    }
 }} | Set-Content ($_.FullName -replace '\.txt$', '_99.txt')
}
}
```

---

please suggest a new code which when given a target folder should:
-catch the first file, append "segment99" to the beginning of the first line (top left corner when opened in a notepad) and save it with the same name +"_99" as suffix.
-go to the next file and do the same
-this continues until all the files in the folder are modified

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Get-Content`. Read and write your file via `[System.IO.File]::Open()` API. Read and write file chunk-by-chunk instead of loading the whole file in memory the way Get-Content does.

Comment: What's your reason for using File.Open over Get-Content?

Comment: OP has identified two problems - the speed and the mangled content. File.Open helps with both where Get-Content exhibits these problems.

Comment: Can't see how File.Open would be any quicker - after all both that and Get-Content would involve using a FileStream, and both would need to read and write the whole file. (As it's being written to a new file) Can you explain why File.Open is quicker? Can see how encoding issues with Get/Set-Content might cause the mangling though. Might they be better of using File.ReadAllText/WriteAllText with an encoding?

Comment: @MrKWatkins: Get-Content reads the whole file to memory and there is nothing you can't do about this. If the file is big that will result in excessive swapping/paging which is slower than the alternative. Where as with File.Open *you* control what parts of file you want load to memory. With this approach you can read the file sequentially and avoid excessive swapping/paging, thus improving performance. Does this address your concern?

Comment: @MrKWatkins: in addition one good advise with performance would be to test when in doubt. Try it yourself: create a big file and write a simple test script that does the processing using both approaches and measure the time taken. Seeing the result with one own eyes is the fastest way to clear any doubts.

Comment: but in this case you need to read the whole file anyway don't you?

Comment: @MrKWatkins: Sure. But the time is not spent on swapping it in and out of memory, since you are not loading the whole file in memory but doing it by small blocks instead. And depending on the size of the file and the amount of free memory this can be a lot faster. I'll update the answer to clarify this bit.